# tailwind sidebar is not fixed

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I know how to make this sidebar fixed but it does not work. I also tried to use "sticky" but it does not work either.
This is the code part that I try to make the sidebar fixed.

```
<div className="flex">
      <aside  className = {`${open ? "w-40" : "w-20"}  p-4 pt-8 duration-300 bg-gray relative sticky top-0 h-screen`}>
        <img
        src={require('../src/assets/control.png')} 
        alt = ""
        className = {`absolute cursor-pointer rounded-full -right-3.5 top-9 w-8 h-8 border-2 border-dark-purple ${!open && 'rotate-180'}`}
        onClick = {() => setOpen(!open)}
        />
        <div>
          <Header data = {open}/>
        </div>
      </aside >
      <main className = "p-7 text-2xl font-semibold flex-1 h-screen">
      </main>
</div>
```

[and this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2wLQ.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. You're adding both relative and sticky classes to your sidebar. Try adding only fixed class instead.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend setting a fixed height for your main content like for example "h-screen" and add "overflow-y-auto" class to it, that way you ensure that your sidebar's end will always remain on the bottom of the screen since you're just scrolling your main content's container.